# Declaring an array of different words

Tags: c

i want to declare an array of this type:

```
char names[] = {"Sam", "Michael", "Greg", "Phil"};
```

Is this syntax correct if not please guide me, i have returned to c++ after a long time. I had been using python .. really missing the simple declarations over there.

Comment: It's easy to try it! And it's highly recommended to read a beginners tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare array of strings, not `char` array.

```
char const * names[] = {"Sam", "Michael", "Greg", "Phil"};
```

Or if you want mutable array:

```
char names[][MAX_NAME_LEN] = {"Sam", "Michael", "Greg", "Phil"};
```

Comment: what if i use this:
string names[] = {"Sam", "Michael", "Greg", "Phil"};

Comment: @jonhopkins It can be `char const *` or `const char *`. Former is simply easier to read from right to left: *"names is array of pointers to constant chars"*

Comment: Yea I just looked it up. Never knew you could do it that way. Personally I think `const char*` is easier to read, but that's just preference.

Comment: @hj-007 `string` is C++ only. In C you have to use `char` arrays.